# About the "delete" command of C++

Tags: c++

I am a new C++ learner. I have a simple question. Here is the code from a book. Is it necessary to create a new pointer, "pCat"? Can I just use the "rCat" and delete it? If not, why?

```
class SimpleCat
{
public:
    SimpleCat (int age, int weight);

    ~SimpleCat() {}

    int GetAge() { return itsAge; }
    int GetWeight() { return itsWeight; }

private:
    int itsAge;
    int itsWeight;
};

SimpleCat::SimpleCat(int age, int weight):
    itsAge(age), itsWeight(weight) {}

SimpleCat* TheFunction();

int main()
{
    SimpleCat* rCat = TheFunction();

    int age = rCat->GetAge();

    std::cout << "rCat is " << age << " years old!\n";

    std::cout << "rCat: " << rCat << "\n";
    // How do you get rid of that memory?
    SimpleCat* pCat = rCat;
    delete pCat;
    return 0;
}

SimpleCat* TheFunction()
{
    SimpleCat *pFrisky = new SimpleCat(5,9);``
    std::cout << "pFrisky: " << pFrisky << "\n";
    return pFrisky;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can just do `delete rCat`. Why do you think you would not be able to do that?

Comment: If that's code from a book a would recommend to throw it away.

Comment: @manni66: Indeed, both the book and the code.

Comment: My solution is only having the "rCat". It works. But the book gives the answer with 2 pointers. That problem talks about the memory leak. I am not familiar with it. I am wondering the one pointer solution may have trouble.

Comment: In this little program there is no reason for the second pointer `pCat`. It just doesn't make any sense to add another variable that will point to the exact same object just for deleting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that definition of `TheFunction`, yes, you should eventually `delete` the return value.  Note you could just `delete rCat;` directly - you don't need to copy it into another pointer `pCat` and then delete that.

However, it would be better if `TheFunction` returned a `std::unique_ptr<SimpleCat>` instead of a raw `SimpleCat*` pointer.

First, this makes it clear that the returned value is something that must be cleaned up, and not for example a pointer to something actually stored somewhere else.

Second, the caller wouldn't need to actually use `delete` at all, since the `unique_ptr` object does that for you.

Comment: Good advice on using `std::unique_ptr`: have an upvote.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you. Now I learn a new command, std::unique_ptr

Comment: @Yue You should [pick up a new book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if it is suggesting you do all this stuff without having given you enough background knowledge. `delete` is an operator and `std::unique_ptr` is a template class, nothing in c++ is called a command

Answer (score 0):

The rule is simple, you need to call `delete` on any pointer that's been allocated using `new`. (And you need to call `delete` exactly once.)

It's not necessary to assign the pointer to another variable, and call `delete` on that.

So therefore you could be even more minimal:

`delete TheFunction();`

would work too, although, of course, you wouldn't be able to do much with the cat.

Comment: Or the most minimal - `delete new SimpleCat(5,9);`.

Comment: @DeiDei: cute .

Comment: @DeiDei poor cat, didn't have a chance to live